# SMS messages notification on my desktop computer?

Tags: samsung, sms, remote-access

Is there any way (application or other) to have PC receive notifications about text messages on Android phone (ability to reply is also welcome)? I don't want to have my messages uploaded to the cloud due to the privacy concerns, so it is preferable to have messages sharing only when using the same wifi network.

I tried using AirDroid and PulseSMS - however both are cloud-based as far as I can tell. I also tried Samsung Flow but did not like it very much (it uses bluetooth instead of wifi for communication).

Please note that this question differs from [this one](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/ask), as I do not want to have my messages cloud-synced.

EDIT: Forgot to add, I have Samsung Galaxy S8 as a phone and use Windows 10 on desktop. Cortana is unavailable in my language.

Comment: Push bullet is highly spoken of. As per this reddit or doesn't use cloud https://www.reddit.com/r/PushBullet/comments/18shwq/how_does_pushbullet_work_encryption_lanonly/

Comment: Haven't used the app yet. See app blog https://blog.pushbullet.com/2015/08/11/end-to-end-encryption/

Comment: @beeshyams Thanks! Encryption looks promising and I will give the app a go if no alternative is available: I would still prefer a solution that does not use any intermediary server though.

Comment: There seems to be alternative http://www.backuptrans.com/tutorial/connect-android-to-pc-via-wifi-for-messages-transfer.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After extensive research I found two programs that seem to offer the desired functionality, that is [Samsung SideSync](http://www.samsung.com/uk/support/side-sync/) and [MyPhoneExplorer](http://www.fjsoft.at/en/). For the time being I have decided to settle down on using the former, as the latter seems to suffer from stability problems (crashes, freezes).

Update: I use [Your Phone](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/your-phone/9nmpj99vjbwv?activetab=pivot:overviewtab) now.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about windows based alternatives, but KDEConnect works locally. You need to be on the same WiFi connection to make it work. Alternatively you can take a look at [this app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=io.Pushjet.api&hl=en) and some suggestions [in this thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/Android/comments/3t6dnz/for_those_looking_for_alternatives_to_pushbullet/)

Comment: Doesn't KDEConnect requires KDE framework installed available for *nix type systems? Does it work on Windows too?

Comment: @Firelord Not the entire DE, just a few dependencies of KDE are required. works fine for me on Ubuntu Gnome. No, it doesn't work on Windows.